# Javascript continue not working even when condition is met

Tags: javascript, continue

The **isPrime()** function returns true if a number is a prime number and it returns false if not. The loop should go through 2 to 500 backward and run it in the **isPrime()** function. **If the number is not a prime number the loop should continue to the next loop iteration.** And also, for the number which is a prime number, it should output in the paragraph's `textContent`, but the continue is not working.

Here is the code:

```
    let i = 500;
    const para = document.createElement('p');

    function isPrime(num) {
      for(let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if(num % i === 0) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;
    }


    // Add your code here
while( i >= 2 ){
 if( isPrime(i) === false){
  continue;
 } else{
  para.textContent = `${i}` + "</br>";
 }
 i--;
}
```

And here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/au9o2ftn/1/

Comment: Your code is different in multiple places.

Comment: The while-loop will be an endless loop as your continue will never reach the i--

Comment: @ethry what do you mean?

Comment: Your fiddle has different JS code to the code block. See line 48 on your fiddle.

Comment: @ethry the fiddle is the same

Comment: @john No, it says `para.textContent = \`${i}\` + <"/br">;` instead of `para.textContent = \`${i}\` + "</br>";` on line 48.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```js
let i = 500;

function isPrime(num) {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}


while (i >= 2) {
  if (isPrime(i)) {
    console.log(i + " is prime!");
  }
  i--;
}
```

without `continue`...

The problem is that when `isPrime(i)` in your original code returns true, it `continue` directly and didn't finish `i--`. As a result, it becomes a dead loop with infinitely checking `isPrime(500)`.

Or, if you wish to keep `continue`, put `i--` before the `continue` statement.

Comment: *If you click Run, you will have to reload the page to access stackoverflow again, it spams alerts on the page.

Comment: @ethry, actually, you can click into another tab and go back and u will see "2" directly. but I will correct that lol

Comment: I used  `para.textContent += `${i} is prime ` + "/n";` instead of console to output it in a paragraph but the /n is not working. It should create a newline. "</br>" and "<br/>" is not working as well. Any ideas?

Comment: @john Please put this in another question, but you keep making so many typos. It is `\n`, not `/n`. For HTML, though, you should use `<br>`.

Comment: @john, `.textContent` only add **text content** to the element. You may try `.innerHTML` in order to make `<br>` to work. (`para.innerHTML+=`)